# Google Calendar Android app doesn't always synchronize

Tags: google-calendar, sync

I use a shared Google Agenda with someone else ("UserA").

If UserA:

- opens his Google Agenda Android app (version 5.8.38-200532405, the latest version)
- adds a new event in our common agenda
- saves the event

then I often don't see it in my own Google calendar (on http://calendar.google.com desktop version for example) even if I refresh the page multiple times (<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or even close/reopen browser).

The only solution we found was that UserA has to click on the 3 dots menu on the top right, then choose "Refresh" (or maybe "Update"?). If he forgets to do "Refresh" after "Save" then it won't be synchronized. This is annoying and not user-friendly: a synchronization **should be automatically triggered** after an event is saved in a shared agenda.

[image]

**Is there a solution to fix this?**

PS: this lead to sometimes not knowing that the other one has added an event :) because he didn't do "Refresh" – the event was not propagated!

Answer (score 0):

UserA needs to have:

- ticked automatic synchronization
- signed in into google account
- allowed synchronization of Google Calendar

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user0. Which "automatic sync" option? Can you add a screenshot? "allowed synchronization of Google Calendar" => where to set this option? (A screenshot is welcome).